# Can we control $CONDITIONS in Sqoop?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

$Conditions break the freeform query in different splits based on the placeholder decided by itself.
Say, we have a query which gives result for 1000 records. By default it will be broken by $CONDITIONS into 4 different queries with boundary conditions

> (1,250) (251,500) (501,750) and (751,1000).

What can we do to achieve query splits according to our requirements?

Comment: is it **offset** and **limit** in query that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Yxn I am trying to understand how we can decide the number of mappers based on split-by and $CONDITIONS.As far as I understood, split-by gives the number of elements while $CONDITIONS divide the query and give to the number of mappers it decides on the basis of data elements. Correct me and regarding **offset** and **limit**, its something that's my next concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't choose query partition offsets. You can control two things:

- `--boundary-query <statement>` for creating splits.
- `--num-mappers` for controlling number of splits.

and obviously `--split-by` column.

Choosing boundaries for each split sounds like a good idea. But it's very costly to get such insights from data.

**How will you know split points?**

By iterating whole data of that particular column and creating some logic to create ideal partition.

*But you can run sqoop job (using default partition) faster than this iteration.*

I guess that's why people are not much interested in this feature.

Comment: Nice explanation

Comment: Thanks @syadav :)